# Angular Html5 validation popup is not showing for two or more fields

Tags: angularjs, html, validation, popup

For some reason Angular validation is not showing `Html5` baloon/popups if we add two or more fields.

Please check these two examples:

1. Example with just one field. Press enter key to validate field and Html5 baloon/popup will show:

https://plnkr.co/edit/oKePef7p4O4AD59eWXe8?p=preview

2. Example with two fields. It doesn't show Html5 baloon/popup on field validation.

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZkDwB40Zhas3yjkT6AdM?p=preview

What is happening here!?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: None of your plunkr are working like you mentioned.

Comment: Checkout this library https://github.com/sagrawal14/bootstrap-angular-validation

Comment: I'm using ng-messages and it's working now! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, none of your *plnkrs* are doing nothing, you're trying to use `ngMessages` module but you didn't put any kind of message error or anything.

Take a look on this simple **demo**:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('ngMessagesExample', ['ngMessages']);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ngMessagesExample">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-messages/1.5.7/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="form">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : form.myName.$touched && form.myName.$invalid }">
        <label for="name">Enter your name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="myName" id="name" ng-model="name" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" required />
        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="form.myName.$error" ng-if="form.myName.$touched">
          <p ng-message="required">This field is required</p>
          <p ng-message="minlength">This field is too short</p>
          <p ng-message="maxlength">This field is too long</p>
          <p ng-message="required">This field is required</p>
          <p ng-message="email">This needs to be a valid email</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : form.myEmail.$touched && form.myEmail.$invalid }">
        <label for="email">Enter your email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="myEmail" ng-model="email" required />
        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="form.myEmail.$error" ng-if="form.myEmail.$touched">
          <p ng-message="required">This field is required</p>
          <p ng-message="minlength">This field is too short</p>
          <p ng-message="maxlength">This field is too long</p>
          <p ng-message="required">This field is required</p>
          <p ng-message="email">This needs to be a valid email</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I'd recommend you to check this [**tutorial**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages) to learn more about `ngMessages`.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Great man, I didn't try with ng-messages. Now is working! Although I thought that Html5 popup/baloon could be used instead ng-messages, but  it doesn't matter.. Thanks